# Redirect to URL After Posting to Google Sheet - Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, navigation

I am trying to redirect to a webpage after posting to a google sheet instead of outputing the text from the return ContentService.createTextOutput command. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Code.gs**

```
const sheetName = 'Sheet1'
const scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function initialSetup () {
  const activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    const doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    const sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    const headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    const nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    const newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'Date' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

I found this code but was not successful in editing mine to make it work.

**Code.gs**

```
var REDIRECT_URL = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";

function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log("POST request");
  Logger.log(e)
  return redirect();
}

function doGet() {
  Logger.log("GET request");
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("form");
  template.url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return template.evaluate();
}

function redirect() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
    "<script>window.top.location.href=\"" + REDIRECT_URL + "\";</script>"
  ); 
}
```

Comment: What does the browser devtools console say?

Comment: Looks like this type of procedure is not allowed: https://chromestatus.com/feature/5629582019395584

Answer (score 0):

According to this page, this type of procedure is not allowed: https://chromestatus.com/feature/5629582019395584

Comment: Did you find an alternative?